# SQS Java lambda getting empty object

Tags: java, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

Getting null object in SQS lambda when I push the object in SQS through java code.

I am pushing order number when an order is created to SQS.

server logs prints following:
2019-01-29 23:22:13 [threadPoolTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG c.a.s.sqs.MessageMD5ChecksumHandler - Message body: {"orderNumber":"201901292322090"}

but when I pull it through lambda. I am getting null in order number
Input: Order [orderNumber=null] (tostring of the object) in AWS lambda code.

I do not understand how ordernumber is not translated properly.

SQS push code:

SendMessageRequest send_msg_request = .... .withMessageBody(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(order))
...

Aws lambda:

public class BookingSQSHandler implements RequestHandler< Order , String > {

```
public String handleRequest(final Order order, final Context context) {
    context.getLogger().log("Input: " + order);
   // send email and return
```

}

getting null order nnumber in aws lambda function.

polled message from SQS, it is fine there but not sure what is happening  with Lambda.[image]

Answer (score 1):

What's the structure and content of your `Order` class?

It's possible that the `orderNumber` property can't be mapped to methods or properties in the `Order` class. You might need to make some changes in the `Order` class itself, for example implementing a setter or ensuring you have appropriate constructors.

Comment: for simplicity, I had only orderNumber for now in order.

Comment: Yes @Learner but what is the actual definition?  Is the value a String, an int, or what?

Comment: Order number is of type string.

Comment: Could you post the structure of your class verbatim? e.g. 
`public class Order { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

The RequestHandler needs to handle an SQSEvent, and not an Order in your example. From the SQS docs:

```
package example;

import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.SQSEvent;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.SQSEvent.SQSMessage;

public class Handler implements RequestHandler<SQSEvent, Void>{
    @Override
    public Void handleRequest(SQSEvent event, Context context)
    {
        for(SQSMessage msg : event.getRecords()){
            System.out.println(new String(msg.getBody()));
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Your actual payload is the JSOn string of the message body.